# Getting error during installing "Android development tools" in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting following error during installing "Android development tools" in Eclipse

"*Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
      Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.7.2120684 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.7.2120684)*"

**I am using windows 7**

[image]

Comment: Are you following the instructions from here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html. You could try following the steps for **Troubleshooting ADT Installation**. Do you have an older versions on the plugin installed?